# to_date function with sysdate

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, sysdate

```
select TO_CHAR(to_date(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'DAY') FROM DUAL;
```

When I run this query the output was : SUNDAY. But we know today is Tuesday(1-1-2013).
And

then changed the query as

```
select TO_CHAR(to_date('01-JAN-2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'DAY') FROM DUAL;
```

answer was :TUESDAY.

then Changed query as

```
select TO_CHAR(to_date(sysdate+1, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'DAY') FROM DUAL;
```

answer is :MONDAY.

When I using the sysdate why it is show SUNDAY as output?

I am new in oracle db. Please help me.

Comment: SYSDATE is already a date.  Why would you think it was necessary to use TO_DATE() on it?

Comment: @APC Now I am studying basics of the oracle, and going through this just tried some examples and this query developed myself from some other query.

Comment: when I using SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD-MM-RRRR'), 'DAY') from dual;  The Ans: TUESDAY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this:

```
 select TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DAY') FROM DUAL;
```

you are using this :

```
 to_date(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

which is giving you date=1/1/0013 which is sunday

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the documentation for sysdate [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm). Sysdate is already a date data type.

Your example query is inappropriate as `to_date` function takes first parameter as String not `date`.

Try the simple query below:

```
     select TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DAY') FROM DUAL;
```

This should return `TUESDAY` as output.

Answer (score 2):

`To_date` is used to convert a strin to date. As `sysdate` is already a date, one must not add add to_date.

Comment: Strictly speaking, sysdate contains both date AND time components. If you, for example, compare sysdate to a DATE field value of today, = comparison will fail. You will need to_date() to make = match.